Read boat fuel gauge resistive 0-190 Ohm and 240-30 Ohm with mcu
I have a project to make wireless gauge reader base on resistive analogue sensor US is 240-30 ohm and europe is 0-190 ohm.
Here is my circuit below

As i don't have the material receive yet is my circuit a good start to read dc voltage on a ads1115.Do the 5volt Dc will affect sender and gauge system?
Nb: the esp32 and gauge system will share the same ground.

None of your ICs are connected to VCC or GND. That wont work. There are no decoupling caps. What goes on in the screenshot above the principle drawing of the analog switch IC? It's too small to see. Control_3 and Control_4 are not connected to anything. I2C of ADS1115  is not connected to anything.

Focus on the SN74HC4066D ic; esp32 and ads1115 are all connected properly even if  they are no show on the diagram.
For control 3 and 4 is same rule as control1 and 2.
The point is not here The point is how to read a variable resistor by injecting small dc amount with a voltage divider to be read by ads115.
If you have a better idear i would be glad to have a comment

We only have the information you supply. When you supply a schematic with lacking functionality, what can we do but give feedback on what is presented?

Is it possible to measure the voltage across a variable resistance? Yes. But: How stable is your 12V? What happens to the voltage on your ADC if the 12V to the variable resistance sensor is varying a lot?

To minimize the effect of the normal 12V battery voltage variation, I would use an A/D that can use an external reference.  Then, if you use the 12V as a reference for the A/D to make the measurement ratiometric, the effect of 12V variation on the measurement will be basically nulled.

That not a problem i can add a small ic to regulate 12dc. The challenge is to read voltage divider with out affecting the gauge by injecting 5dc on the sender

Affecting the gauge how?

I have read in a similar other post that by open  the 5dc circuit  to read the voltage divider  the niddle of  the gauge move.


The challenge is to read voltage divider with out affecting the gauge

It's not a challenge. Just about any op-amp will do it. Never connect automotive signals directly to any IC - neither op-amp nor an ADC. It will just get destroyed by the large transients expected on those signal lines.
I have no idea what you need that analog switch and various resistors for. None of that is necessary.
There are many possible gauge implementations, but they will all generate some usable voltage on the sender. All you need to do is to read that voltage from the sender.
Below is a schematic with a hypothetical gauge that drives about 1mA into the sender, and has a 200mV full-scale voltmeter as the readout device.
The interface circuit applies 16x gain to the voltage on the sender, and some low-pass filtering, and that voltage is then read by the ADC.
R1 limits the fault current through D1 in case of overvoltage. R2 limits the current through the input protection diodes of the op-amp OA1.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I don't known if you have forgot Monica but what a serious circuit you shared is the most pro i have seen in StackExchange about the subject many thanks i going to study it carefully and come back to you many over thanks for that share.

In your circuit witch dc supply do you use for TLC272 ?

@KhalesNaim TLC272 or 2272 runs from 3.3V or 5V - same as the A/D converter. There are many other op-amps that will work here as well. The main factor is that the op-amp is rail-to-rail on the output, and on input can measure signals down to ground. Typically you'd look for a RRIO i.e. Rail-to-Rail Input/Output op-amp. There are many types nowadays, designed for low voltage operation. Microchip has very many available, as do all major analog chip manufacturers.

Thank Kuba your circuit work as expected.
Received the rod sender and the gauge from aliexp
i have reduice the gain with 30k R in place of 150k because of over gain the range Vdc of the sender is about from 0 to 0.807v  relative to gnd when full .
more questions .
1 What happen to this circuit if sender reach 5 V value  relative to ground .I tried  this config it's over range.
2 I want to make an universal electronic gauge system for nmea 2000 boat the problem is that voltage value across sender gauge vary from  manufacturer , I read some example  that can reach 7.5 V.
